# Converting "complex" JSON data in to a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to convert the following JSON data

```
"{\"errors\":{\"base\":\"Invalid field.\"}}"
```

in to a hash accessible this way:

```
@internal_test1[:errors][:base]
# => "Invalid field"
```

**How to do that?**

---

**UPDATE**

```
@internal_test1 = "{\"errors\":{\"base\":\"Invalid email/password combination.\"}}"
test = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@internal_test1)
@internal_test2 = test["errors"]
```

The debug is

```
@internal_test1
--- "{\"errors\":{\"base\":\"Invalid email/password combination.\"}}"

@internal_test2
--- 
base: Invalid email/password combination.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
> @internal_test1 = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode "{\"errors\":{\"base\":\"Invalid field.\"}}"
 => {"errors"=>{"base"=>"Invalid field."}} 
> @internal_test1["errors"]
 => {"base"=>"Invalid field."}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was wrong. I would like to access at the '[base]' "level". That is, I need to convert it in to a "fully" hash.

Comment: Did you try it? It is a hash. `@internal_test1["errors"]["base"]` will work there.

Comment: Are you trying to use symbols or strings as the keys? JSON.decode gives you strings as keys. Post some output from your console, and let's see what's going wrong.

Comment: I must use '@internal_test1["errors"]["base"]' instead of '@internal_test1[:errors][:base]!!!